# Tail a log file and send rows to curl in 100 line batches

Tags: bash, curl, awk, influxdb, xargs

I have a bash script that looks like this:

```
tail -f -n +1 my.log | \
  awk -f influx.awk | \
  xargs \
  -I '{}' \
  curl \
  -XPOST 'http://influxdb/write?db=foo' \
  --data-binary '{}'
```

What can I change so that instead of creating a `curl` request for each row, it would batch them up into say 100 rows (see [influx curl docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/guides/write_data/#writing-multiple-points))?

The problem I'm having is that each InfluxDB "point" needs to be separated by a new line, which is also the delimiter for `xargs` e.g. adding `-L 100` to `xargs` doesn't work.

Bonus: how would I also make this terminate if no new lines has been added to the file after  say 10s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `xargs`, you want to use `split`, with its `--filter` option. For example, the following batches lines into groups of two:

```
$ seq 5 | split -l 2 --filter='echo begin; cat; echo end'
begin
1
2
end
begin
3
4
end
begin
5
end
```

In your case, you could try something like

```
tail -f -n +1 my.log | \
  awk -f influx.awk | \
  split -l 100 --filter='\
    curl \
      -XPOST "http://influxdb/write?db=foo" \
      --data-binary @-'
```

The `@-` makes `curl` read data from standard input.

Comment: This is great, I didn't know about split. One small issue is that it doesn't seem to send the last n lines (where n < 118). Is there something that can be done to improve that?

Comment: Ah, the problem seems to be with `tail -f` if I just use `tail -n 20`, for example,  it works as expected. Any thoughts?

Comment: The problem with `tail -f` is likely to be with buffering. Because `tail -f` never terminates, `awk` or `split` won't know to process the last, partial buffer. You could try adding `-u/--unbuffered` to split? If that doesn't work, you may need to look at buffering in `awk`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `-u` didn't do anything for me in `split`.
Adding `system("")` to the end of the awk script helped.
However, it's still missed the last batch, but that's better than before than one batch due to the buffering.